# form buttom disable onsubmit but form is not submited in javasc

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

```
<script>
function disableButton() {
    var button = document.getElementById('accept');
    button.disabled = true; 
    return true;
}
</script>

<form class="form-horizontal" name ="reg" method="post" action="" onSubmit="return disableButton()"/>

<button class="btn btn-info" name="sub" type="submit" id="accept">
    <i class="icon-ok bigger-150"></i>
    Submit
</button
```

When I hit submit button button is disbled but form is not submitted

Kindly any one please do favour

Comment: First thing I notice is that the `disableButton()` function has no closing brace, also I suggest `onSubmit="return false;"`; and in turn use the button to submit the form.

Comment: Then, what is that `<button>` for?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to add functions to your forms, you can simply catch your form submit, disable the button and allow it continue afterwards:

HTML Part:

```
<form class="form-horizontal" id="reg" name="reg" method="post" action="" />
```

Javascript Part:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var form = document.getElementById('reg');

if (form.attachEvent) {
    form.attachEvent("submit", processForm);
} else {
    form.addEventListener("submit", processForm);
}

function processForm(e) {
    if (e.preventDefault) e.preventDefault();

    var button = document.getElementById('accept');
    button.disabled = true;

    return true;
}
</script>
```

If you wish to test it out, change above to `return false;`. This will disable the form submit and only disable the button.

Answer (score 0):

Your function does not follow proper syntax. But other than that there's no real reason to return true or false...

```js
var acceptor = document.getElementById("accept");
acceptor.addEventListener("click", toggleButton);

function toggleButton() {
  acceptor.disabled = "disabled"
}
```

```html
<button class="btn btn-info" name="sub" type="submit" id="accept">
  <i class="icon-ok bigger-150"></i>
  Submit
</button>
```

Also, your button tag is not closed `<button> </button>`...

You can simply define the attribute are defined as a boolean true or false, which means you can specify their value and leave everything else out. i.e. Instead of disabled="disabled".

You may want to consider a function buttonToggler... so you can later switch it back easily (although I'm not sure this will help you...

Also... have the script at the bottom of the body rather than the top in-case of a preloading issue (this is not a foolproof solution to the problem where the JS loads faster than the HTML).

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function toggleButton() {
var acceptor = document.getElementById('accept');
if acceptor.disabled === true{
acceptor.disabled=false;
} else {
acceptor.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
} 
</script>
```

Try that.

Comment: check out the Snippet? notice button cannot be clicked... at this point what browser are you running the test on? you also have to run the function... did you? call the function like this toggleButton(); Or you can have it on click become disabled... if you'd like when would you like it to be disabled after submit?>

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<?php echo "<pre>";var_dump($_POST); echo "</pre>";?>
<script>
    function disableSubmit() {
        var button = document.getElementById('accept');
        button.disabled = true; 
        myNiceForm.submit();
    }
</script>

<form class="form-horizontal" id="myNiceForm" name ="reg" method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];?>">
    <input type="text" name="myTestText"/>
    <input id="accept" type="submit" onclick="disableButton()"/>
</form>
```

Things to consider:

- If you want your HTML form to be posted, it needs to have a proper
  value for the `action` attribute.
- The button with the id of `accept` doesn't cause the form to be
  posted, you also don't have any client-side script to do so, and it's
  not a good practice, so a submit button has been added to the form.
- When you click the submit button, the `disableSubmit()` function
  invokes, and disables the button, and finally submits the form
  programmatically, however, it's not necessary.

Comment: @user3049432 That button disables, however, the act of disabling and then submitting happens so quickly, that you may not see at all, however, to see that you may insert a breakpoint in the code on the line of submission.